# Getting color value in gradient corresponding to value

Tags: python, colors

I have 2 arrays, one with `colors` to gradient, second for value `breakpoints`.

```py
breakpoints = [0.1, 1.25, 2, 2.5, 3.3, 4.2, 4.9, 5.8, 6.7, 7.7, 8]
colors = ['#4290FB', '#4FC0FF', '#4FFFD5', '#7CFF4F', '#F6F05C', '#FF8068', '#FF4E6F', '#C645B8', '#6563DE', '#18158E', '#000000']
```

If the input value is less than first element set the color to `#AAAAAA,` if it's over 8 set it to `#000000`

[image: Gradient example rendered with matplotlib]

Colors on graph are values between `0-8` and those are gradients between two elements of colors, array distances between those points are the breakpoints. How can i get color from point of this graph by value so for example `2.8` will be `#77FF5C` etc.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer to my question. I used the `spectra` library
My code:

```py
import spectra

polylinear_scale = spectra.scale([ spectra.html(x).to("lab") for x in (['#4290FB', '#4FC0FF', '#4FFFD5', '#7CFF4F', '#F6F05C', '#FF8068', '#FF4E6F', '#C645B8', '#6563DE', '#18158E', '#000000']) ])
polylinear_negpos = polylinear_scale.domain([0.1, 1.25, 2, 2.5, 3.3, 4.2, 4.9, 5.8, 6.7, 7.7, 9])

def getDiffColor(value:float=0):
    if value <= 9:
        return polylinear_negpos(value).hexcode
    elif value <= 0.1:
        return "#AAAAAA"
    else:
        return "#000000"
```

It's not good but it works.